# ProLiant ML150 G3 and HP-UX

Tags: hardware, hp-ux

Does the ProLiant ML150 G3 support HP-UX?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves to go negative, except that it started on the wrong forum.

Comment: I'm going to say that it's not a real question for this site either.  It's a simple fact lookup.  Something that Google finds on the first hit.  Not really appropriate for this site (which attempts to build a knowledgebase of things are NOT simple fact lookups...).

Answer (score 2):

No. HP-UX only runs on PA-RISC and Itanium processors.

Answer (score 2):

Chris is correct, as you can also see from the [HP-UX article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_UX), and I'd also add that if you're asking if a generic x86 server runs HP-UX you probably don't know what HP-UX is and then you probably don't need it :)